# Micronaut how to set a Property name based on another Property in Application.yaml

Tags: micronaut

I am using micronaut 3.x framework
and I have a dynamic service name and to configure it in the application.yml I'm trying to set it up using

```
service_name: test-db

vcap:
  services:
    test-db:
      credentials:
        hostname: 10.1.02.0

my_service: ${vcap.services.${service-name}.credentials.hostname}
```

It fails parsing the document, trying using 2 different properties

```
my_property: vcap.services.${service_name}.credentials.hostname
my_service: ${my_property}
```

In this case it can compose the property name correctly but it uses that content as a string, not resolving it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As of Micronaut 4.0 there's a support for an [Expression Language](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#evaluatedExpressions) which is similar to Spring's [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

If you upgrade to Micronaut 4.0 you could do

```
my_service: #{properties['vcap.services.' + properties['service-name'] + '.credentials.hostname']}
```